# Typescript for HOC with required props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I have a component `MyComponent` that takes in some props and one of them is optional:

```
type Props = {
   a: string;
   b: number;
   c?: string;
}
```

I wrote a higher-order component that adds some functionality based on property `c`. In order for it to make sense, I decided to make property `c` on HOC required:

```
type CProps = Props & {
  c: string;
};

export const withC = (WrappedComponent: ComponentType<CProps>) => {
  const WithC = (props: CProps) => {
     ///...
  }
  return WithC;
};
```

Now, typescript is complaining when I try to do this:
`const MyComponentC = withC(MyComponent);`

saying that property `c` is required on `withC` but not on `MyComponent`.

How do I bypass this, ideally without changing the props type of `MyComponent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type CProps = Props & {
  c: string;
};

export const withC = (WrappedComponent: ComponentType<Props>) => {
  const WithC = (props: CProps) => {
     ///...
  }
  return WithC;
};
```

`WrappedComponent` should not have a required `c` yet, but `WithC` should.

Answer (score 0):

WithC will always run even if you didn't pass c prop. so you have to call that function if c prop is passed

Comment: I know that, and I am. But in the meantime, would like to get rid of a  typescript error.